# WebStorm - discord.js - "Element is not exported"

Tags: discord.js, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

For some reason, I and many others have had the issue with WebStorm and Discord.js, specifically it doesn't recognize some of the (re-)exported modules from the package; in this case those from Builders seem to be the ones with the issue:

[image: WebStorm does not know of ButtonStyle]

Yet as suggested for discord.js@14.7.1 I do not have Builders installed:

```json
{
  "main": "bot.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "7.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.1.0-canary.0",
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "chartjs-node-canvas": "^4.1.6",
    "croner": "^4.2.2",
    "discord.js": "^14.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fuse.js": "^6.5.3",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "konva": "^8.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.1",
    "npm": "^8.13.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sort-by": "^0.0.2",
    "string-similarity-js": "^2.1.4",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas why WebStorm fails to know about what Discord.js re-exports?

```js
`-- discord.js@14.7.1                                                        
  `-- @discordjs/builders@1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the `discord-api-types` library and importing it from there.

```js
import { ButtonStyle } from 'discord-api-types/v10';
```